# Isaiah 8:11: "kaf" or "bet"?

Tags: mesorah-tradition, spelling-variants, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

[image: isaiah 8 11 in the aleppo codex]

It seems that two versions of Isaiah 8:11 exist.

One has  "כחזקת היד" -- this is the version in the Aleppo (shown above) and Leningrad codices:
    http://www.studylight.org/desk/?sr=1&old_q=Isaiah+8%3A11&search_form_type=general&q1=Isaiah+8%3A11&s=0&t1=iw_ale&ns=0

One has "בחזקת היד " -- this is the version in Mikraot G'dolot and all [the commentators there](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%97_%D7%99%D7%90) (Yonatan, Rashi, Radak, Metzudot).

Does anyone have any light to shed on this?

Comment: Mira Bernstein, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you'll look around and find other information that interests you, perhaps including our 15 other [Isaiah questions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isaiah-yeshaya-the-book). Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: _Shhhhh don't tell everyone._

Comment: Wikitext has it with a כ: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%97_%D7%99%D7%90

Comment: @Ephraim As they should. Mikraot Gedolot goofed. No big deal.

Comment: Where's your evidence, AA? I haven't seen a printed version of ישעיה that has a כ- it's not just the מקראות גדולות.

Comment: @Ephraim He brought the evidence in the question! What do you think the printed texts you are looking at are based on? The answer is always Bomberg until certain printings in the last 100 years or so.

Comment: OK, I found one with a כ: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42109&pgnum=42 . And indeed, it's a recent printing.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what light you want shed on this other than not to trust the Mikraot Gedolot for fine issues of proper *nusach hamikra*. The [Aleppo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleppo_Codex), [Leningrad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leningrad_Codex), [Bodmer](http://www.e-codices.unifr.ch/en/list/one/cb/0021), [Damascus](http://jnul.huji.ac.il/dl/mss/heb5702/index_eng.html), and [Cairo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex_Cairensis) Codices (9th to 12th centuries) all have a כ. Bomberg's Mikraot Gedolot (2nd edition, 16th century, seen below) has a ב. [Bomberg's edition is notorious for small errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikraot_Gedolot#The_Ben_Hayyim_edition), but its popularity (as with many early printed materials) allowed for many of his mistakes to creep into common usage. Just to add to the *point*, you'll see he goofed on the *dagesh kal* which should be in the beginning of the same word in question.

[image: isaiah 8 11 in bomberg's mikraot gedolot second edition with typos]

For the curious, neither בחזקת or כחזקת appears elsewhere in Tanach, so nothing can be proven from the ליתא.

Comment: Fascinating, and it's interesting how one printed edition could cause so much confusion. It's similar to the decisions that lead to the less clear versions of Tosafot that appear in all editions of Shas. See: http://printingthetalmud.org/essays/4.html .

Answer (score 2):

For what's its worth, here's the version from the Dead Sea Scrolls:
[image: isaiah 8 11 in the dead sea scroll]

See it here: http://dss.collections.imj.org.il/isaiah?id=17:11#8:11

So that version, also has the word spelled with a "kaf".

Comment: This is not meant to be an answer, just another interesting piece of information.

Comment: So shouldn't it be a comment?

Comment: Yes. I'm not aware that there's a way to post an image in the comments.

Comment: You can post links to images in comments just like you would post any other link.